# Unable to insert/update the data in Media table through impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm trying to make an entry of an image in the media for email template related customizations as given below:

```
$contentCatalog=ContentCatalog_en
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]
$jarResourceCms=jar:com.test.core.setup.CoreSystemSetup&/core/import/cockpits/cmscockpit
INSERT_UPDATE Media;$contentCV[unique=true];code[unique=true];mime;realfilename;@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator][forceWrite=true]
;;EmailPageModel_preview;text/gif;EmailPageModel_preview.gif;$jarResourceCms/preview-images/EmailPageModel_preview.gif
```

How ever,I keep getting the below error in the logs while tryng to import this part of impex.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 | [mde.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: line 60 at main script: current handler is not set[HY--1]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importNextInternal(Importer.java:763)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importAll(Importer.java:708)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at com.pearson.core.jalo.StoreConfigJobPerformable.importImpexFile(StoreConfigJobPerformable.java:121)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at com.pearson.core.jalo.StoreConfigJobPerformable.importStoreConfigurations(StoreConfigJobPerformable.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at com.pearson.core.jalo.StoreConfigJobPerformable.perform(StoreConfigJobPerformable.java:49)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob.performCronJob(ServicelayerJob.java:38)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1301)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:819)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.access$1(Job.java:772)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job$JobRunable.run(Job.java:677)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.util.threadpool.PoolableThread.run(PoolableThread.java:198)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 | Caused by: de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: current handler is not set[HY--1]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.processLine(ImpExImportReader.java:692)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.readLine(ImpExImportReader.java:495)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:254)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importNextInternal(Importer.java:757)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     ... 10 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: current handler is not set
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator.getHandler(MediaDataTranslator.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator.performImport(MediaDataTranslator.java:153)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.header.SpecialColumnDescriptor.performImport(SpecialColumnDescriptor.java:132)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processUpdateLine(DefaultImportProcessor.java:581)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processInsertUpdateLine(DefaultImportProcessor.java:409)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processItemData_Impl(DefaultImportProcessor.java:244)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processItemData(DefaultImportProcessor.java:149)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/07/26 09:51:57.699 |     at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.processLine(ImpExImportReader.java:659)
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you paste the class 'MediaDataTranslator.java', especially at line :104 ? There is definitly something wrong with the @media statement

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please do the system update then try to execute below Impex.

```
# Preview Image for use in the CMS Cockpit
```

## Import config properties into impex macros

$contentCatalog=xxxjapanContentCatalog
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged]

INSERT_UPDATE Media;$contentCV[unique=true];code[unique=true];mime;realfilename;@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator][forceWrite=true]
;;EmailPageModel_preview;text/gif;EmailPageModel_preview.gif;$jarResourceCms/preview-images/EmailPageModel_preview.gif

Answer (score -2):

Have you did any custom configuration with any of the code?

Reference:

```
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12756314/impexexception--javalangillegalstateexception-curr.html
```